# uniform continuity on an infinite semi-interval [1; +inf]

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous map defined on $[1; +\infty)$ and differentiable on $(1; +\infty)$.
Let also suppose that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)$ exists.

Is the function uniformly continuous at $[1; +\infty)$?

The correct answer is "yes". Please explain the effect of the derivative at infinity on the function itself.

Comment: If the limit exists then $f'$ is bounded for $x > L$ for some $L$ and so the mean value theorem tells you something there. The interval $[1,L]$ is compact so that tells you something. A little care is needed to stitch the two results together. But this is the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0) Let $M >0$; $f$ is uniformly continuos on compactum $[0,M]$.

1) $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x)=: L$, real.

Let $\epsilon$ be given. There is a $M>0$ s.t.

$x >M(\epsilon)$ implies $|f'(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

For $x \in (M,\infty):$ $|f'(x)|$ is bounded,

i.e. $|f'(x)| <B(M)$.

Hence

$ |f(x)-f(y)| = |f'(t)||x-y| \le B(M)|x-y|,$

$t\in (\min(x,y),\max(x,y)).$

In $(M,\infty)$ $f$ is Lipschitz hence uniformly continuos.

2) For a $\epsilon/2$ there is a $\delta_1$ for $[0,M(\epsilon)]$, a $\delta_2$ for $(M(\epsilon),\infty)$.

Let $\delta =\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$.

3) What happens if $x\in [0,M]$, and $y \in (M,\infty)$?

Comment: Disciple. Can you handle point 3) above?